# Laravel: Unknown column type "timestamp" requested

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

I am trying to perform a migration and I am getting the following problem.

> Unknown column type "timestamp" requested. Any Doctrine type that you use has to be registered with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::addType(). You can get a list of all the known types with \Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Type::getTypesMap(). If this error occurs during database introspection then you might have forgotten to register all database types for a Doctrine Type. Use AbstractPlatform#registerDoctrineTypeMapping() or have your custom types implement Type#getMappedDatabaseTypes(). If the type name is empty you might have a problem with the cache or forgot some mapping information.

My code is the following:

```
Schema::table('XXXXXXXX', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->timestamp('start')->change();
        $table->timestamp('end')->change();
    });
```

The strange thing is that I have already performed migrations with that type of data:

```
Schema::create('XXXXXX', function (Blueprint $table) {
        ...
        $table->timestamp('date_expired')->nullable();
        ...

    });
```

Does anyone know how to fix it or see the error I'm doing.

Thanks

---

UPDATE

> In the end I have deleted the migration, I have modified it putting timestamp in the necessary columns and I have executed it again. (Having deleted the table before from the database)

Comment: `public $timestamp` value is true or false for very first scheme of your question ?

Comment: I do not understand the question

Comment: What are the changes of end and start?

Comment: Every Model have there own timestamp. If you dont want timestamp in your model then you need to `public $timestamps = false` do this.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent#timestamps check this

Comment: The previous code
$table->time('start');
$table->time('end');

Comment: I do not have $timestamps in this table

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I make doctrine support timestamp columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774628/how-do-i-make-doctrine-support-timestamp-columns)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the laravel docs page you can find a warning telling you that there are certain types that you can't use with the `->change()` method.

[Link to laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#updating-column-attributes)

It also says this:

> To modify a timestamp column type a [Doctrine type must be registered.](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/migrations#prerequisites)

Comment: In the end I have deleted the migration, I have modified it putting timestamp in the necessary columns and I have executed it again. (Having deleted the table before from the database)

Comment: @AgustínTamayoQuiñones, to modify a timestamp column type, we can use raw DB queries: `DB::unprepared('alter table users modify created_at timestamp default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP not null;');`.